# how can npm init stencil works?

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

Can anyone explain me why

```
npm init stencil
```

works without install it globally?

I'm used to use library and all 
should be installed globally so
I don't understand why stencil
work like that ....

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stencil` is the initializer for the [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) command. The way the command works is that it utilizes a package with the name `create-<initializer>` to bootstrap the project.

For Stencil that package is https://npmjs.com/create-stencil.
The source is on Github: https://github.com/ionic-team/create-stencil.